# How to reference the conents of a variable instead of a variable in Java

Tags: java

Ok, I'm trying to make a quick double validator for any JTextField in a program. I would like to pass this to a function which then checks the contents of a field, makes sure it's a double, then return it as a double to the function.

Here is what I have so far but theTF.getValue() should get the value of the string, not the string itself.

```
    public double valDouble(String theTF)
    {
            double theDouble;
            try
            {
                theDouble = theTF.getValue();
                return theDouble;
            }
    }
```

How can I run the getValue() on the contents of the string?

Edit:
Ok, I somewhat screwed up my meaning. I understand the parseDouble, but I left it out on accident here is what I have now:

```
    public static double valDouble(String theTF)
    {
        double theDouble;
        try
        {
            theDouble = Double.parseDouble(theTF);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e3)
        {
            theDouble = 0;
        }
        return theDouble;

    }
```

My Real issue is theTF represents the name of a TextField. I need the value OF the text field not the value in theTF. I'd like to have this here to, perhaps, highlight the field red etc.

**Answer**(Thanks Hunter):
The best way was to pass the Object, not sure why I was trying to parse out the value of a string reference.

```
    public static double vDbl(JTextField theTF)
    {
        double theDouble;
        try
        {
            theDouble = Double.parseDouble(theTF.getText());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e3)
        {
            theTF.setText("Invalid");
            return 0;
        }
        return theDouble;
    }
```

Comment: Why not just pass the JTextField object to the method?

Comment: @Hunter Ah, true, I don't know what I was thinking! Thanks, put it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Since you can pass the JTextField, why not pass JTextField.getText()? Your double validator has no reason to have access to a TextField object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be passing the JTextField object to your method to get the information you are looking for, I don't even know if it's possible to get the JTextField object from just its name; maybe with reflection, but for this application reflection seems overly complex.

ex:

```
public double valDouble(JTextField theTF)
{
        try
        {
            return Double.parseDouble(theTF.getText());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            System.err.println(nfe.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Double class to convert it..

```
public Double valDouble(String theTF)
{
        Double theDouble;
        try
        {
            theDouble = Double.valueOf(theTF);
            return theDouble;
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I left out the parseDouble, I was asking how to get the value of a JTextField object where theTF sends the name of.